# Symfony | buildForm | CollectionType не принимает null

Tags: angularjs, symfony

подскажите, пожалуйста, по моему вопросу!
Front: Angular
Back: Symfony

1. С Front отправляю поле complectations со значением []
2. Обрабатываю на Back в buildForm

```
->add('complectations', CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type' => NumberType::class,
    'allow_add' => true,
])
```

3. В итоге получаю

```
0: {complectations: []}
```

---

- Если бы была возможность заменять [] на null было бы все отлично.
- При отправке с Front вместо [] значение null возникает 500 ошибка с невалидным значением.
- Подскажите, как быть.

Comment: добавить allow_delete ?

Comment: Вот тут достаточно описано это 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#delete-empty